# How to register the result of a PowerShell expression in a variable for a DSC?

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc

I am trying to configure an Azure VM with Azure Automation DSC. One of the resources I want to set is DNS on the client workstation with `xDnsServerAddress` from [`xNetworking`](https://github.com/PowerShell/xNetworking) module.

The problem is that it requires an interface alias and interface aliases change on Azure VMs vary depending on deployment (mainly VMs seem to get either `Ethernet` or `Ethernet 2`).

I can query the interface name locally using the following cmdlet expression:

```
$Interface=Get-NetAdapter|Where Name -Like "Ethernet*"|Select-Object -First 1
$InterfaceAlias=$($Interface.Name)
```

I don't know, however, how to use it inside the DSC.

My DSC configuration is as below (only the relevant part):

```
Configuration MyDscConfig
{    
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName xNetworking

    # place-1

    Node $AllNodes.where{$_.Role -eq "Workstation"}.NodeName
    {

        # place-2

        xDnsServerAddress DnsServerAddressSetToDc1
        {
            Address        = '10.0.0.4'
            InterfaceAlias = $InterfaceAlias
            AddressFamily  = 'IPv4'
            Validate       = $true
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I place the cmdlet expression either in `place-1` or `place-2` the compilation job fails with:

> The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The term 'Get-NetAdapter' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I assume it tries to execute `Get-NetAdapter` on the pull server, but I may be misinterpreting the error message.

How can I register the result of the cmdlet expression on a destination machine and register it in `$InterfaceAlias` variable for the `xDnsServerAddress` resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot perform a query keep the results of the operation and use it to declare the next state (See notes at the end of the answer.)

You can work around this limitation using the [documented workaround/solution from xNetworking](https://github.com/PowerShell/xNetworking#set-a-node-to-use-itself-as-a-dns-server), which will find an active ethernet adapter named `Ethernet1` if it does not, it will find the first active ethernet adapter and make sure it is named `Ethernet1`.  Then, use a resource to set the DSC server address on `Ethernet1`.

**This is investigational, names and parameters are subject to change. The DSC team is investigating a better way to do this.**

```
Configuration SetDns
{
    param
    (
        [string[]]$NodeName = 'localhost'
    )

    Import-DSCResource -ModuleName xNetworking

    Node $NodeName
    {
        script NetAdapterName
        {
            GetScript = {
                Import-module xNetworking
                $getResult = Get-xNetworkAdapterName -Name 'Ethernet1'
                return @{
                    result = $getResult
                }
            }
            TestScript = {
                Import-module xNetworking
                Test-xNetworkAdapterName -Name 'Ethernet1'
            }
            SetScript = {
                Import-module xNetworking
                Set-xNetworkAdapterName -Name 'Ethernet1' -IgnoreMultipleMatchingAdapters
            }
        }
        xDnsServerAddress DnsServerAddress
        {
            Address        = '10.0.0.4'
            InterfaceAlias = 'Ethernet1'
            AddressFamily  = 'IPv4'
            DependsOn = @('[Script]NetAdapterName')
        }
    }
}
```

*Notes:*

There is a question in the comments.  The summary of the question is if querying turns the declarative paradigm into an imperative paradigm.

Answer:

> I don't believe querying turns it into an imperative paradigm, but you
>   currently cannot perform a query keep the results of the operation and
>   use it to declare the next state.
>
> This currently forces us into something a little further away from
>   declarative for the problem that I would like.  **My personal opinion** is that we
>   should work with what we have and write resources that query and set a
>   known state.  Then, use the known state through the rest of the
>   configuration (a form a declarative-relative, per your terminology).
>
> The DSC team has this similar [UserVoice
>   suggestion](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/13399734-returning-information-from-dsc-resource-to-another)
>   we are using to track this request.  Please upvote it if you think this
>   is a useful feature.

Comment: Yup, [I wrote that](https://github.com/PowerShell/xNetworking/commit/521166bef8373f72438d2f7643ead8e31daf61ce), but I would call it a disclaimer.

Comment: Added.  This is the best way I know of currently.  This solution works with both pull and push configurations.  Fundamentally, it's very similar to the solution you (@techraf) came up with.  As DSC is supposed to be a declarative language, it's better though to separate the resource of setting the DNS server for the NIC and search for the NIC.  This solution keeps the imperative language separated from the declarative.  Hopefully, in the long term, the DSC team can come up with a better way to query a value and use it as a parameter later in the configuration.

Comment: Does querying for a state and performing declarative operation based on that state turn the paradigm into an imperative one? This is not a rhetorical question, I'm really curious. Isn‘t declarative-relative possible in addition to declarative-absolute?

Comment: @techraf my response was longer than allowed in a comment.  I added the response as notes in my answer.

Comment: Update based on your feedback.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the DSC Node Configuration (which is a MOF file) must have all the values set at the time of compilation.

As a workaround I decided to use a PowerShell script resource instead of `xDnsServerAddress` (some values below are hardcoded to match the example in the question):

```
Script DnsServerAddressSetToDc1
{
    GetScript = {
        Return @{
            Result = [string](get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias (Get-NetAdapter|Where Name -Like "Ethernet*"|Select-Object -First 1).Name -AddressFamily IPv4).ServerAddresses
        }
    }

    TestScript = {
        if (([string](get-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceAlias (Get-NetAdapter|Where Name -Like "Ethernet*"|Select-Object -First 1).Name -AddressFamily IPv4).ServerAddresses) -eq '10.0.0.4') {
            Write-Verbose "DNS server set"
            Return $true
        } Else {
            Write-Verbose "DNS Server not set"
            Return $false
        }
    }

    SetScript = {
        Set-DnsClientServerAddress `
            -InterfaceAlias (Get-NetAdapter|Where Name -Like "Ethernet*"|Select-Object -First 1).Name `
            -ServerAddresses 10.0.0.4 `
            -Validate `
            -ErrorAction Stop
    }
}
```

Comment: This is similar to the [documented solution here](https://github.com/PowerShell/xNetworking#set-a-node-to-use-itself-as-a-dns-server)